# Microsoft Project Export Map, copying the map itself

Tags: export, ms-office, ms-project

I have created a project export map in Microsoft Project->File->Save As->Type .xlsx->Selected Data->Use Map-> and have created a map for export.

Is there a way to copy the map itself to another install of Microsoft Project on a different computer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You need to put the map into an .mpp file. If it's not in an .mpp file already, use the Organizer to copy it from the Global to an .mpp file and take that file to the other computer and use the Organizer to copy it into that computer's Global.

The Organizer can be found here:

- In Project 2007, from the menu choose: Tools -> Organizer...
- In Project 2010, choose: File -> Info -> Organizer

p.s. This is technically a [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) question as it is related to the application and not programming .