# Import Excel into Microsoft Project

Tags: excel, vba, ms-project

I would like to create an automated tool to import the excel for Microsoft Project file. I am trying to achieve this in VBA (please suggest me, If any other options there) and i researched some code for basic setup.

I found following link to setup the system and code to do this automation but still not sure below code is exact my findings or not.

Sources :

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-automate-ms-project-from-excel-app-malcolm-farrelle?trk=portfolio_article-card_title

[Automate creating n Microsoft Project files from an excel file with n rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389578/automate-creating-n-microsoft-project-files-from-an-excel-file-with-n-rows)

> I would like write the update script using Mapping field and
> create/append as new projects.

**Update**

With help of below answer, I have rewritten the code to import the multiple files and saved it as *.mpp file.

but the problem is mpp file is opening and it should happen in the backend user should not view naything.

**Code:**

```
Private Sub ImportButton_Click()
    On Error GoTo Exception
        
    Dim InputFolderPath As String, DefaultInputFolderPath As String, DefaultOutputFolderPath  As String
    Dim fileExplorer As FileDialog
    
    InputFolderPath = ""
    DefaultInputFolderPath = "D:\Sample Projects\MPP Import\Input\"
    DefaultOutputFolderPath = "D:\Sample Projects\MPP Import\Output\"
    Set fileExplorer = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
     'To allow or disable to multi select
    fileExplorer.AllowMultiSelect = False
    If fileExplorer.Show = -1 Then 'Any folder is selected
        InputFolderPath = fileExplorer.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    Else
        InputFolderPath = DefaultInputFolderPath
    End If
       
    Call CreateProjectFromExcelFile(InputFolderPath, DefaultOutputFolderPath)
    
Exception:
    Select Case err.Number   ' Evaluate error number.
        Case 0
            Exit Sub
        Case Else
            MsgBox "UNKNOWN ERROR  - Error# " & err.Number & " : " & err.Description
    End Select
    Exit Sub
ExitCode:
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Public Sub CreateProjectFromExcelFile(InputFolderPath As String, DefaultOutputFolderPath As String)

    Dim myFile As String, myExtension As String, oFullFilename As String, oFilename As String
  

    ' get access to Project application object
    Dim appMSP As MSProject.Application
    On Error Resume Next
    ' see if the application is already open
    Set appMSP = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
    If err.Number <> 0 Then
        ' wasn't open, so open it
        Set appMSP = CreateObject("MSProject.Application")
    End If
    ' return to whatever error handling you had
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    appMSP.Visible = False
      
    MapEdit Name:="ImportMap", Create:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True, DataCategory:=0, CategoryEnabled:=True, TableName:="Data", FieldName:="Name", ExternalFieldName:="Task_Name", ExportFilter:="All Tasks", ImportMethod:=0, HeaderRow:=True, AssignmentData:=False, TextDelimiter:=Chr$(9), TextFileOrigin:=0, UseHtmlTemplate:=False, IncludeImage:=False
    MapEdit Name:="ImportMap", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Duration", ExternalFieldName:="Duration"
    MapEdit Name:="ImportMap", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Start", ExternalFieldName:="Start_Date"
    MapEdit Name:="ImportMap", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Finish", ExternalFieldName:="End_Date"
    MapEdit Name:="ImportMap", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Resource Names", ExternalFieldName:="Resource_Name"
    MapEdit Name:="ImportMap", DataCategory:=0, FieldName:="Notes", ExternalFieldName:="Remarks"
    ' open the Excel file to import
    Dim strFilepath As String
    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
    myExtension = "*.xlsx"

    'Target Path with Ending Extention
    myFile = Dir(InputFolderPath & myExtension)
            
            'Loop through each Excel file in folder
    While myFile <> ""
        If (myFile = "") Then
            MsgBox ("No files avaalable!")
            GoTo ExitCode
        End If
        
        'This example will print the file name to the immediate window
         strFilepath = InputFolderPath & myFile
         
         oFullFilename = Right(strFilepath, Len(strFilepath) - InStrRev(strFilepath, "\"))
         oFilename = Left(oFullFilename, (InStr(oFullFilename, ".") - 1))
         
         appMSP.Visible = False
         
         appMSP.FileOpenEx Name:=strFilepath, ReadOnly:=False, Merge:=1, FormatID:="MSProject.ACE", Map:="ImportMap"
         appMSP.FileSaveAs Name:=DefaultOutputFolderPath & oFilename & ".mpp"
        'Set the fileName to the next file
         myFile = Dir
    Wend
    appMSP.FileCloseAllEx pjDoNotSave
    Set appMSP = Nothing
    MsgBox ("Imported Successfully...")
ExitCode:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Be more specific about "runtime error while reading objMSP value" as `objMSP` is the application object. What line is causing the error. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The code you show demonstrates automating (controlling) MS Project from MS Excel VBA. If you are having problems with that, change your question to remove the parts about importing. If you question really is about importing, be specific about what you are trying to do. For example, are you trying to create a new schedule from an Excel file? Or update task values from an Excel file? Show a screen shot of your data in Excel and Project.

Comment: @RachelHettinger I am very specific that, i would like to create new schedule or update schedule from an existing Excel but i am not sure how to start with VBA. Can you please provide some sample. I will update you the screenshot of Excel.. also, how can i use the mapping fields in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to create an automated tool to import the excel for
> Microsoft Project file.

Automating making a new Microsoft Project file from an Excel file is very easy—it's a single command: [FileOpenEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Project.Application.FileOpenEx).

Here is how you can do it from Excel:

```
Sub CreateProjectFromExcelFile()

    ' get access to Project application object
    Dim appMSP As MSProject.Application
    On Error Resume Next
    ' see if the application is already open
    Set appMSP = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ' wasn't open, so open it
        Set appMSP = CreateObject("MSProject.Application")
    End If
    ' return to whatever error handling you had
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    appMSP.Visible = True
    
    ' open the Excel file to import
    appMSP.FileOpenEx Name:="C:\<your path here>\SampleNewProjectForImport.xlsx" _
        , Map:="<your map name here>"
    
    appMSP.FileSaveAs Name:="MyProject.mpp"
    
End Sub
```

Update the paths/names in the FileOpenEx line with your names, add error handling and other code as you want, and add a reference to the Project Object library.

Note: If you don't know how importing works in MS Project, see [Import Excel data into Project](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-excel-data-into-project-cb3fb91a-ad05-4506-b0af-8aa8b2247119) for an explanation of how the process works.

Note 2: The same command is used to append to or update an existing schedule.

Comment: A big thanks for the sample code. Where can we handle the mapping fields here, because i have saved my mapping in wizard method. Where can we handle it in my code. If you don't mind, my email id is Vigneshkumar957@gmail.com, can you please ping me, i would like to have more information about this.

Comment: The `FileOpenEx` has a parameter named `Map`; this is where you pass in the name of the map you saved when doing the Import Wizard. In my code example, replace <your map name here> with the name of the map you saved. That's all you have to do—it really is as easy as that. If you need a new map, go through the wizard again to create one (you can have many saved maps). Note: maps cannot be created in VBA.

Comment: Thanks again. my query is, how can i have the Map globally, i want to create this macro and share it with multiple project manager. if that the case, they wont be have same mapping in their machine right? Can i get your email address?

Comment: I am getting runtime error as "1004 Application define or object define error".

Comment: Yes, maps are stored in the global.mpt file or in a regular .mpp file. See [Microsoft Project Export Map, copying the map itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182918/); this applies to import maps as well.

Comment: Okay got it. Let me try this and come back to you. but i am getting that above run time error

Comment: Richel, I have build the code with your help and its working but everything should happen in the backend. i have updated my code. can you help me

Comment: Leave the Visible property set to False if you want, but it is not recommended as it makes dealing with unexpected results difficult. Automation is all about controlling one application from another—the application must be opened and running in order to automate it.

Comment: You are right, but when it comes to 100 / 500 excel to import, thats not good practice to show all right?

Comment: Rachel, Thanks for your help. Can you please help me here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62554305/convert-excel-data-to-ms-project-mpp-using-vba

Comment: Create 100+ schedules at one time?? And do it frequently enough that you don't want the user bothered by it? I support companies that use half that many for multi-year, $100M+ projects... Perhaps you want to re-think how you plan to use the application.